# laravel 8 serializeDate() must implement interface DateTimeInterface, null given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have upgraded my Laravel project from 6 to 7 and then to 8, I have followed all the documentation upgrade steps but unexpectedly I faced an error with `serializeDate()` function.

I created it inside the model and then called it inside the resource but it ended up with this error:

> TypeError Argument 1 passed to App\Models\User::serializeDate() must
> implement interface DateTimeInterface, null given, called in
> /var/www/html/POS_Ibra/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php
> on line 23 (View:
> /var/www/html/POS_Ibra/resources/views/user/user_detail.blade.php)

My model file :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table    = 'users';
    protected $hidden   = ['id', 'password', 'role_id'];
    protected $fillable = ['slack', 'user_code', 'fullname', 'email', 'password', 'init_password', 'phone',
                           'profile_image', 'role_id', 'status', 'is_admin', 'created_by', 'updated_by'];

    

    public function parseDate($date): ?string
    {
        return ($date != null) ? Carbon::parse($date)->format(config("app.date_time_format")) : null;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
     *
     * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
     * @return string
     */
    public function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
    {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

And here is my resource file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'slack'            => $this->slack,
            'user_code'        => $this->user_code,
            'created_at_label' => $this->serializeDate($this->created_at),
            'updated_at_label' => $this->serializeDate($this->updated_at),
            'created_by'       => $this->createdUser,
            'updated_by'       => $this->updatedUser
        ];
    }
}
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5buP1.png)

[my model file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSeyR.png)

[resource file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2kRq.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by removing the data type as the following:

```
public function serializeDate($date): ?string
{
    return ($date != null) ?  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : null;
}
```

it's worked for me!